# Differential Pair routing insight for USB 2.0 circuit involving a USB C connector with multiple D_N and D_P pins

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, differential, impedance-matching

I'm bringing USB 2.0 into a PCB design from a USB C receptacle. I've already accounted for the 5.1k resistors needed but I'm stumped on how best to run a differential pair with DP1, DP2, DN1 and DN2 on my PCB layout. I would appreciate any insight on how best to manage this. My prior experience has been with USB micro 2.0 with single lines of D_P and D_N. Do I tie them together with vias bridging on top and then perform a diff pair? Or do I connect both with a "U" loop and run a longer length with diff pair? I'll happily adjust my question if it is too vague. Thank you for any insight.
[image: Staggered D_P and D_N pins that need differential pairing]

Comment: For USB 2.0 there is not too much pairing consideration to have as long as you don't go overboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can tie both DP and DN signals together to form a single diff pair. At USB 2.0 speeds the way you tie them together is not very important. Of course you will always have a long nub in the form of the unused wire in the cable that can degrade the signal, especially with longer cables. You can get around this by using multiplexer ICs designed for this case such as the USB3740. With these chips you will need some way to recognize the USB C plug orientation and that can be done by looking at the CC lines or using another dedicated chip such as the UTC2000 which does this for you.